# Dockerfile not installing latest pypi version

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile

I have the following Dockerfile to create a container with Flower.

```
FROM python:alpine

# Get latest root certificates
RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates && update-ca-certificates

# Install the required packages
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir redis flower
RUN pip install future

# PYTHONUNBUFFERED: Force stdin, stdout and stderr to be totally unbuffered. (equivalent to `python -u`)
# PYTHONHASHSEED: Enable hash randomization (equivalent to `python -R`)
# PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE: Do not write byte files to disk, since we maintain it as readonly. (equivalent to `python -B`)
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 PYTHONHASHSEED=random PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Default port
EXPOSE 5555

# Run as a non-root user by default, run as user with least privileges.
USER nobody

ENTRYPOINT ["flower"]
```

The current pypi version of Flower is 0.9.5.

Yet, when I build the container, the version installed is 0.9.4 so I have to manually upgrade the package with `pip install flower --upgrade` to get the 0.9.5 version.

I don't get why the latest version is not installed in the first place, could you explain it to me ?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to show the output from the `pip install` step? Including Python version and `pip` version.

Comment: No repro; I copy/pasted your `Dockerfile` and got `Downloading flower-0.9.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (459 kB)`

Comment: Is it using the Docker build cache, and you had previously built it with the older version?

Comment: Re: @DavidMaze's comment, what happens if you build with `--no-cache` (`docker build --no-cache ...`)?

Comment: (If you're using a tool like [Pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/stable/), then `COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock .` in the Dockerfile would repeat the installation, but only when one of those files changed.)

Comment: @tripleee do you mean the output of my manual `pip install` ? I did build it with the older version before, but I don't know if I'm using the build cache (new to docker). I'll try with `--no-cache`. I'm using a `requirements.txt` file for other containers but not this one.

Comment: I mean that part of the output from `docker build` (or probably better yet simply all of it, if it's not too bulky).

Comment: @tripleee I only get this kind of info when I `docker-compose build flower` : `Step 3/8 : RUN pip install --no-cache-dir redis flower ---> Using cache ---> 401f9c2909da`. So I guess it is using cache indeed, but why ?

Comment: It always does, unless you tell it not to.

Comment: OK so the solution is to use the `--no-cache` option when I need to upgrade it ? I'll probably try to use a docker specific tag image instead of using my own Dockerfile for the future (but I did it on purpose because the docker image was not updated at that time). Thx for your help btw !